# Rails - Routing and def update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 4 with Devise for user authentication. I'd like to collect additional inputs from users at a later stage (on another page).

my routes.rb

```
put 'users/color' => application#update
```

form html:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_color_path, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :what_is_your_favorite_color %>
  <%= f.text_field :color, class:"form-control" %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end

end
```

A few questions on the above process:

Since my user methods are handled by devise, should I create a new `def update` method in the controller above? If so, what should be in it?

Do I need to update the sanitizer commands with the new field?

I don't have strong_params in my application_controller. Do I need it here?

Where do I put the form code? Paste it within a devise view folder?

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not doing it right way

If you want to update users. Add UsersController

In routes.rb

```
resources :users, only: [:update, :edit]
```

In app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load_user

  def update
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  end

  private

  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:color)
  end
end
```

In app/views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

In app/views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :what_is_your_favorite_color %>
  <%= f.text_field :color, class:"form-control" %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: rake routes shows me the url for the above as users/:id. Going to a route like users/68 shows `No route matches [GET] "/users/68"`

Comment: above routes will generate put "/users/:id"

Comment: How do I get to the form view so users can fill it out?

Comment: the users/edit route takes me to the default devise route. Should I change the resources name to something else so it doesn't clash with devise? Will this work even though I want to update the model called User?

Comment: I currently have devise_for :users in my routes. does this cause the resources :users route to clash